# How should I reply to "Dude, are you there?"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

Let's say I am having a telephone conference with rest of the team, and somebody asks me "Dude, are you there?"  How should I reply?

> Yes, dude, I am there.

or

> Yes, I am here?

It is difficult for me to see the difference.

Comment: Is your question about the difference between *here* and *there* when on the phone?

Comment: The correct answer to the question "Dude, are you there?" is always "No."

Comment: Consider also, "Dave's not here man."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

English was developed prior to the advent of instantaneous, long-distance, voice communication and so the use of spatial deictics is not so cut and dry. In normal cases, *here* means "close to the speaker," and *there* means "close to listener and/or far from both parties," but there are cases in phone conversations where *there* is more appropriate for a speaker to use in referring to his/her own location. For example, when speaking to someone who has a mistaken idea of your location:

> A: You're supposed to be waiting in front of the restaurant.
>   
>   B: I'm already there, on the north side.

In the *Dude, are you there?* example, however, I do think that it sounds more appropriate to say *Yeah dude, I'm here.* Saying *I'm there* sounds slightly awkward in such a situation, but not nearly as awkward as saying *Yes, dude*.

Consider also the use *now*, a temporal deictic, which usually, but doesn't always mean "at the time of speaking/writing."

Answer (score 12):

In phone conversations, *here* refers to where you are and *there* refers to where the person you're talking to is.